# Verify file format is csv on import by determining delimiter and checking all columns are included with .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, import

I am busy doing a project where I have to add import and export functionality. I was able to quite easily make the export functionality work. Here is my question regarding Import:

I was able to make a template with 3 columns : stock_code;item_name;price
All future imports will only have these 3 columns. Now here is my question:

1. How can I determine the delimiter on import?
   I have done the following on the file input

   <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="File" accept=".csv/text/plain"

This sets the browse window to - custom files and not All files. The problem here is if they do set it to all files, I need to determine the delimiter so there is not an error.

2.In addition to determining delimiter I need to make sure that the file is only 3 columns

Useful Info:
I do have CSVHelper nuget package
and im working on asp.net mvc 4.6

Please help

Comment: one question: ***why*** do you use _semicolons_ as delimiter in a _comma separated file_? also: what have you _tried yourself_ so far to fix your _two_ distinct problems?

Comment: sorry I do use commas that was a typo, so far I have tried to write a JS function to look for the most used delimiter but it does not seem to work or I might have written it wrong, because it has to look for those before it uploads to the system. The reason I think I couldn't get it work is that I need it to if for some reason the user uses points, or like I mistakenly just did semi colons it needs to change it to commas. @FranzGleichmann

Comment: I then cleared the JS Function and tried using the NuGet package CSVHelper but I was not familiar enough with it to be completely honest with you been stuck on this for like a week now

Comment: What do you mean when you say "import"? Are you trying to load the CSV data into a different system, like a SQL database, or just verify the format of the file when it is uploaded to your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written code that implements a "delimiter detector for csv data", so I can describe the strategy that I used. First, I defined a set of "acceptable delimiters" ordered by priority: ',', '\t', ';', '|'. Those are the most common delimiters that I've seen in use.

Then, I read the first line of data out of the csv, this could be done with StreamReader.ReadLine(). I then iterate over every character in the line, and keep track of how many times I see each delimiter. The delimiter that was seen the most is the winner.

This works quite well, especially when the first line in the file is a header row that contains mostly alpha character. However, for some cultures it is common to find ',' used as a decimal point in numbers, and they tend to use ';' as the CSV delimiter. If the first row is all numeric values with decimal points (no headers) then this algorithm can mis-detect ',' as being the delimiter. I doubt this would likely ever happen in practice.

My implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan/blob/c8aefa55b7f00900bff4e914591fd855f4052a9d/source/Sylvan.Data.Csv/CsvDataReader.cs#L227-L254). There is a bit extra complexity because I'm processing data out of an intermediate buffer; that could be simplified if you adapted it to your own needs.

Depending on what you intend to do with the CSV data you could use the library that this code lives in: Sylvan.Data.Csv. It is available as a nuget package.

```
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;
...

// by default, detects delimiter and assumes a header row is present
var csv = CsvDataReader.Create("MyData.csv");

if(csv.FieldCount != 3) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid file");
}

while(csv.Read()) 
{
  if(csv.RowFieldCount != 3) {
    // the row contains a different number of columns than expected
    throw new Exception("Invalid row at " + csv.RowNumber);
  }
  var stockCode = csv.GetString(0);
  var name = csv.GetString(1);
  // this next line would throw a FormatException if the the price column doesn't contain
  // a numeric value
  var price = csv.GetDecimal(2);

}
```

Comment: Thanks This worked perfectly few minor teaks because to answer your comment to my question above it was both we had a template.csv file on our system that they download and import into the system and SQL we needed the above solution to stop users from posting other files and incase they did we needed to make sure we had away to set delimiter from causing a break on the system THANKS for our help